# Axlsx_rails. Set height of multiple rows at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xlsx, axlsx

I'm generating `*.xlsx` files using [`axlsx_rails`](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails) based on [xlsx](https://github.com/randym/axlsx) gem.

I'm setting height for single row like this:

> sheet.add_row [1,2,3,4,5,6], :style => predefined_style, :height =>
>   14.3

How could I set height for a batch of rows, and if it possible, which declaration has higher priority?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best I know of is to set the height on each row:

```
sheet.rows.values_at(1,2,5,6).each {|row| row.height = 40}
```

If necessary you can gain access to the sheets through the workbook:

```
sheet = workbook.worksheets.first
# or
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("Sheet Name")
```

Whichever statement comes later has priority (meaning it isn't like CSS where inline has higher priority.)

Comment: Thanks for fast response @noel!